# Confluent schema-registry does not start always

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I type "confluent start schema-registry" and it boots up zookeeper, kafka and fails at the schema registry. A minute later I type the command again, it finds that zookeeper and kafka are running already and starts the schema-registry without an issue.

I can't nail down the root cause. It is obviously something timing related. Once it can bring up all services, once it fails at the kafka already, most of the time it is like above.

Error message in the schema-registry.log

```
ERROR Server died unexpectedly (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: No supported Kafka endpoints are configured. Either kafkastore.bootstrap.servers must have at least one endpoint matching kafkastore.security.protocol or broker endpoints loaded from ZooKeeper must have at least one endpoint matching kafkastore.security.protocol.
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.endpointsToBootstrapServers(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:615)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.bootstrapBrokers(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:555)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.<init>(KafkaStore.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:139)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:59)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:41)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:165)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
```

Comment: same or similar issue, not sure what to make of it

Comment: Nice if you respond

Comment: Interestingly, in Confluent 3.x.x all was working nicely. Problems started with the fresh install of 4.1.0, issue remains in 4.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Try by setting in config file kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Comment: Does not change the probability of working/not working unfortunately.

Comment: well it worked for me, but I got a newer problem and solved that. What does your log say? All works now.

Comment: the same message? installed on same machine?

Comment: Same message. As said, it is about the timing and not failing always. Same server, yes.

Comment: OK, then I had an issue with the persistency level of topic creation - I looked in the logs which I am not sure is the above stuff or not. Most annoying for sure. May be an idea to install on a  clean server, that was something some did in the past. Good luck then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this from the docker-compose file like kafka-clusters.yml (having > 1 instance) following is the right way to add ENV variable values -

```
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka-broker-1:9092,kafka-broker-2:9092,kafka-broker-3:9092'
```